# Conditional PL SQL Procedure not working

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am writing a simple PL SQL procedure. However it throws me statement ignored error. Do I need to call them into individual variables and then insert into the final table? please check the code below.

```
  PROCEDURE EMP_MAIN IS BEGIN

FOR CUR1 IN
      (SELECT STG.INT1 INT1
    , STG.OPT1 OPT1
    , STG.FDT1 DT1
        , STG.HDR_SRC_LEAD_ID HDR_LEAD_ID
    , STG.HDR_SRC_NAME HDR_SRC_NAME
    FROM MAIN_EMP STG)

  BEGIN  IF (INT1 IS NOT NULL)
    THEN 
    INSERT INTO EMP_FIN(
                                          ROW_ID
                                        , INT
                                        , OPTION
                                        , DATE
                                        , TYPE                                      
                                        , RATING
                                    )
                 VALUES
                                    (
                                       ROWNUM
                                     , CUR1.INT1
                                     , CUR1.OPT1
                                     , CUR1.DT1
                                     , 'Prospect'
                                     , '1'
                 );
            COMMIT;
            END IF; END EMP_MAIN;
```

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: An hint: start by creating a simpler procedure, to check how the `CREATE PROCEDURE` works and then, when you'll be able to create a procedure that only does `null;`, try to add some code.

Comment: You are missing `LOOP...END LOOP`. `FOR CUR1 IN (...) LOOP <statements> END LOOP;`

Answer (score 0):

This code approaches this problem all wrong and uses Oracle [a set based processing engine] to implement a row-at-a-time/slow-at-a-time process.
I recommend instead, simply:

```
INSERT INTO EMP_FIN (ROW_ID, INT, OPTION
                                        , DATE
                                        , TYPE
                                        , RATING
                                    )
SELECT rownum, STG.INT1 INT1
    , STG.OPT1 OPT1
    , STG.FDT1 DT1
    , STG.HDR_SRC_LEAD_ID HDR_LEAD_ID
    , STG.HDR_SRC_NAME HDR_SRC_NAME
    FROM MAIN_EMP STG
    WHERE INT1 IS NOT NULL;
```